# Nuget difference beetween DNXCore5.0, NETCore4.5 and .NETPlatform5.2

Tags: .net, nuget, dnx, .net-core

I've seen Nuget Packages targeting both Platforms! What's the difference between them? I think NETCore4.5 is the new OpenSource .NET Platform (DotNetCore), but what's .NETPlatform5.2 and DNXCore5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`netcore45` is Windows 8 Apps, `dnxcore50` is DNX/ASP.NET 5 running on CoreCLR, `dotnet52` is the next evolution of portable (think of it as `portable-net451+netcore451+wpa81` but future-proof). For more information, see the [.NET Platform Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md) wiki page.

Comment: Too bad that the wiki page isn't very future proof.  Keeping it updated is pretty important.